# Capture only two finger touch and pass all other clicks etc through the div

Tags: ipad, events, touch

I have an iframe with a div on top of the iframe. What I would like to do is capture any two finger touch on the div and if the div detects a single finger touch/click etc then pass that event through to the iframe beneath the div. I understand that I can use pointer-events: none to pass all clicks etc through an element to the iframe beneath it. But this would also pass the two finger touch/click. I want the div on top to pass everything that isn't a two finger touch and capture the event when there is a two finger touch. Does this seem possible? Thanks ahead of time for the help.